# How to import appcompatdelegate?

Tags: android-studio, import

I am trying to import

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate;
```

However, it says won't be resolved ("cannot resolve appcompatdelegate"). I have updated my Android Support Repository and Android Support Libraries.
I synced the gradle. I have android studio 1.2. I have Android Repository 14 and Support Library 21.1.1,

Comment: Have you tried to run manually Gradle sync after the update? Which version of Android Studio you have installed?

Comment: I synced the gradle. I have android 1.2. I have Android Repository 14 and Support Library 21.1.1

Comment: Ok, I have only two ideas. First try to delete and install again both Support repository and Support library. The next is in Android Studio:
File -> Invalidate caches / Restart

Comment: And only for sure, have you added dependency in your build.gradle?: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.1.1'

Comment: I went to the gradle. Appcompat was in the build.gradle file but it was an older version. So I changed the phrasing. It told me "Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.1.1 Error(23,13)". It gives me the option to Install Repository and sync project. So I did. I restarted, rebuild and resync the program. Now it gives me contradicting messages. Gives me the same error but it also says that project sync is successful. Alot of my functions are now in red and say "cannot resolve ".

Comment: Have you tried to test it also on new created project? File -> New -> New project -> Blank activity -> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.1.1' to build.gradle and in the main activity: import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate; ?

Comment: I tried compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+' instead. It syncs. But import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate; is still unresolved. I'll try it on a new project.

Comment: Same issue with the new project when using compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.1.1'

Comment: It's working now. No idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Just like:

```java
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate;
```

or with AppCompat

```java
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate;
```